# python connecting to ssh An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

When I try connecting to my server

```
class ConnectToServer():

    def connect_to_vps(self):
        port = 22
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(self.IP, port=port, username="root", password="123", timeout=3)
        ssh.close()
scanner = ConnectToServer()
scanner.connect_to_ssh()
```

I get this error which is,

> paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

This only happens SOMETIMES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing your connection inside your function at ssh.close(), isn't it the problem?

Comment: I believe it should connect, than close